# Given two rectangles A and B and their dimensions, is a there test for lengthA<lengthB, widthA<widthB

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

If we have two rectangles and their dimensions, is there a mathematical test to simultaneously compare the two numbers. For examples, if we wanted to compare the area, we would compare the products, but that doesn't tell us if both dimensions are larger in one rectangle or just their product.

Another way to phrase this problem would be, given two pairs of numbers $(a,b)$ and $(p,q)$, is there a function $f(x,y)$ such that if $f(a,b)<f(p,q)$ then $a<p$ and $b<q$? That is, can we use a single comparison to determine whether the rectangle with dimensions $(a,b)$ can be contained in one with dimensions $(p,q)$?

Comment: What do you mean "larger in one triangle"? Do you mean "larger in one dimension"? And what do you mean by "test" or "method"? Which operations do you allow? What about logical operations? The signum function? Assymetric subtraction? Maximum and/or minimum?

Comment: sorry, I meant rectangle. does that clear it up?

Comment: No, the "size" of a rectangle is not clear. You probably mean "dimension" or "side". And you have not answered the other questions.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused because I haven't used the word "size" in my question. But to clarify that line, I meant that, when comparing areas, we can only be sure that one rectangle is larger in at least one dimension but I want to see if there is a way to compare both dimensions simultanously. I should have specified the operations: all mathematical operaitons are allowed but I feel like logical operators lead to trivial answers

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's wrong with $a < p \land b<q$?

Comment: @user251257 You're not comparing the two simultanously you're comparing them one by one. I'm looking for a characteristic in a pair of numbers that can be used to compare both of them at the same time

Comment: so you want an arithmetic expression without logical operators? are min, max, or abs allowed?

Comment: abs is allowed, min and max are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to determine whether $(a,b)$ is a smaller rectangle than $(p,q)$ using just a single comparison. Let us write $(a,b)<(p,q)$ whenever $a<p$ and $b<q$ and never any other time. Essentially, the problem we have is that, in the real numbers, the following is true:

> If $x$ and $y$ are distinct real numbers, then either $x>y$ or $y>x$.

However, we find that we have pairs like $(2,2)$ and $(1,3)$ where neither can be said to be greater. We will call such pairs incomparable. In a technical sense, we are saying that the real numbers are *totally ordered* and rectangles are only *partially ordered*. This can quickly be exploited to show the non-existence of such an $f$.

Let us consider the four rectangles $(4,1),\,(1,4),\,(2,2),\,(3,3)$. We can see that we need $f(1,4)=f(4,1)$ since, if they differed, our lemma above would say one was greater and either $(1,4)<(4,1)$ or $(4,1)<(1,4)$, neither of which is true. In fact, the only comparison that exists in our set of rectangles is $(2,2)=(3,3)$, but to get the rest to be incomparable we need $f(4,1)=f(2,2)$ and $f(4,1)=f(3,3)$ implying that $f$ is constant on this set - meaning it cannot be used to compare anything.

In fact, in more generality, we can prove that to satisfy the condition $f(a,b)<f(p,q)$ implies $(a,b)<(p,q)$, we need to set $f$ to a constant, in which case it's not very useful for comparing anything.

Comment: I would have thought that the "one comparison that exists" would be written $(2,2)<(3,3)$. Of course as you immediately prove, other facts require that $f(2,2)=f(3,3)$ (which I think completely answers the question with a resounding "no").

Answer (score 0):

In a rectangle we mostly take the longer side as length and the shorter side as width.

Let $a\text{ and }b$ be the length and breadth of one of the rectangle respectively; similarly and $p\text{ and }q$ be the sides of the other rectangle.

Then if,
$$\frac{|a+p|}{2} + \frac{|a-p|}{2} = a\qquad\implies\quad a\gt p$$

Simlarly if,
$$\frac{|b+q|}{2} + \frac{|b-q|}{2} = b\qquad\implies\quad b\gt q$$

Comment: but this isn't simultanous. You might as well just use a<p∧b<q. I'm looking for a method of the form: if f(a,b) < f(p,q) then a < p and b < q